# Django / MySQL / Python Programming Error ( 1064)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, django-3.1

when I run python manage.py migrate I keep getting the following error.

**django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'None) NOT NULL, `user_id_id` integer NOT NULL)' at line 1")**

I'm running Python 3.8.6, and mysqlclient 2.0.1 and Django 3.1.3.

**Model**

```
from ..assets.provinces import PROVINCE_CHOICES
from ..assets.industries import INDUSTRY_CHOICES
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class GrantProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             models.SET_NULL,
                             blank=True,
                             null=True)
    province = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=PROVINCE_CHOICES,
        help_text="Province your organization is based out of"
    )
    company_size = models.IntegerField(help_text="Company size")

    industry = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        choices=INDUSTRY_CHOICES,
        help_text="Industry your organization is part of."
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "grantprofiles"
```

**View**

```
# Grant Profile View
from rest_framework import viewsets
from ..serializers.grantprofile import GrantProfileSerializer
from ..models.grantprofile import GrantProfile


class GrantProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GrantProfileSerializer
    queryset = GrantProfile.objects.all()
```

**Admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ..models.grantprofile import GrantProfile


# Grant Profile Admin

class GrantProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'province', 'company_size', 'industry')


admin.site.register(GrantProfile, GrantProfileAdmin)
```

**Serializer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.grantprofile import GrantProfile


class GrantProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GrantProfile
        fields = ('user_id', 'province', 'company_size', 'industry')
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have a typing mistake. In serializer, you have typed **user_id**. There is no such field in your **GrantProfile** model. It should be **user**. And also you have imported GrantProfile model twice in serializers.

Comment: So I changed the user -> user_id but that wasn't the issue. The error is saying that the I'm running the wrong syntax for the query.